# PowerApp Forms export & import

Tags: powerapp, forms-7

Just using customized forms in powerapps, is there a way to export and import the form?

i need to move it from a site collection.

if this can't be acheieved is there a default template in sharepoint to open in powerapps itself when creating a new item in the sharepoint list?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently this functionality does not exist.

[Source:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/customize-list-form) Under the "Managing your custom list form" section the last question is as follows

> **Q:** Can I move my custom list form from one list to another? 
>   **A:** No. This functionality is not currently supported

Answer (score 0):

Lists along with custom forms can be migrated using Flows and Apps Migrator:

https://github.com/Zerg00s/FlowPowerAppsMigrator

```
Flow & Power Apps Migrator also helps you migrate SharePoint lists that are used as a dependency for your Apps and Flows. There is an interactive UI form that lets you do just that.

Finally, the Flow & Power Apps Migrator c**onverts SharePoint List Forms customized with Power Apps**.
```

[▶️ Video Tutorial](https://youtu.be/0TB080BNS1A)